# Shell script error: unexpected end of file

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh

cd "$(dirname "$0")"

if wget  https://www.ischool.utexas.edu/~sowmya92/book.png; 
then
     eips -g book.png
else
     eips -g error.png
fi
```

I tried to run this but says, then expected.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? What is this supposed to do? What doesn't work?

Comment: the ";" ater the if should be used if you put "then" on the same line. Drop it if you use a "newline" instead, like on your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd "$(dirname "$0")"

if wget -q "https://www.ischool.utexas.edu/~sowmya92/book.png";
then
     eips -g book.png
else
     eips -g error.png
fi
```

Or

```
#!/bin/sh

cd "$(dirname "$0")"

if wget -q https://www.ischool.utexas.edu/~sowmya92/book.png
then
     eips -g book.png
else
     eips -g error.png
fi
```